# How to use public SOCKS4 proxy system wide?

Tags: proxy, socks

I'm using Pop!_OS 20.04. Firefox has built-in proxy settings. So, there's no problem. I can use proxy on `wget`, `curl`, `apt` using proxychains. But, it's not system wide. I tried `gnome-control-center` (Network > Network Proxy > Manual and added proxy server and port but, didn't work at all).

I also tried `nmcli`

- `nmcli con edit CONNECTION_NAME`
- `set proxy.method auto`
- `set proxy.pac-script proxy.pac`

Here's my `proxy.pac`

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {    
SOCKS4 *proxy*:*host*
}
```

But, that's also not working.

Answer (score 0):

At least on my system, `man nmcli` has this to say about the `proxy.pac-script` value:

> proxy.pac-script
>
> Read the JavaScript PAC (proxy auto-config) script from file or pass it directly on the command line.
> **Prefix the value with "file://" or "js://" to force one or the other.**

So you might want to do it this way:

```
set proxy.pac-script file:///full/path/to/proxy.pac
```

Also, your `proxy.pac` format might be incorrect. I'm not proficient with JavaScript, but as far as I know, it should be like this:

```
function FindProxyForURL (url, host) {
  return 'SOCKS4 proxy_host:proxy_port';
}
```

If you want to use a proxy for connecting to specific host(s) only, you might need to do something like this:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    if (shExpMatch(host, "somehost*")
        || shExpMatch(host, "*.some.sub.domain")) {
        return "SOCKS4 proxy_host:proxy_port";
    }
}
```

More examples in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config